# Jackson serialize exclude object from list

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, fasterxml

Following JSON have some parent and child relationship (sample data)

- "id": 1050 is child because it has "parentId": 1051
- "id": 1051 is parent because it has "parentId": null

Like this i have huge data

```
      {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusMessage": "Success",
        "dataCount": 0,
        "data": null,
        "dataList": [
          {
            "id": 1050,
            "parentId": 1051,
            "questionInfo": {
              "id": 1050,
              "description": "--",
              "question": "--",
              "answersInfo": [
                {
                  "id": 2041,
                  "description": "--",
                  "isCorrect": "--",
                  "name": "--",
                  "subQuestions": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 2040,
                  "description": "--",
                  "isCorrect": "--",
                  "name": "--",
                  "subQuestions": []
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 1051,
            "parentId": null,
            "questionInfo": {
              "id": 1051,
              "description": "--",
              "question": "--",
              "answersInfo": [
                {
                  "id": 2024,
                  "description": "--",
                  "isCorrect": "--",
                  "name": "--",
                  "subQuestions": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 2023,
                  "description": "--",
                  "isCorrect": "--",
                  "name": "--",
                  "subQuestions": [
                    {
                      "id": 1050,
                      "parentId": 1051,
                      "questionInfo": {
                        "id": 1050,
                        "description": "--",
                        "question": "--",
                        "answersInfo": [
                          {
                            "id": 2041,
                            "description": "--",
                            "isCorrect": "--",
                            "name": "--",
                            "subQuestions": []
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 2040,
                            "description": "--",
                            "isCorrect": "--",
                            "name": "--",
                            "subQuestions": []
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "-------": "-------"
          }
        ],
        "dataMap": null
      }
```

My requirement is need to remove child records from parent position where parentId has some value ("parentId": 1051), because these child info coming in parent sub info those records are not parents

```
      {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusMessage": "Success",
        "dataCount": 0,
        "data": null,
        "dataList": [
          {
            "id": 1051,
            "parentId": null,
            "questionInfo": {
              "id": 1051,
              "description": "--",
              "question": "--",
              "answersInfo": [
                {
                  "id": 2024,
                  "description": "--",
                  "isCorrect": "--",
                  "name": "--",
                  "subQuestions": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 2023,
                  "description": "--",
                  "isCorrect": "--",
                  "name": "--",
                  "subQuestions": [
                    {
                      "id": 1050,
                      "parentId": 1051,
                      "questionInfo": {
                        "id": 1050,
                        "description": "--",
                        "question": "--",
                        "answersInfo": [
                          {
                            "id": 2041,
                            "description": "--",
                            "isCorrect": "--",
                            "name": "--",
                            "subQuestions": []
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 2040,
                            "description": "--",
                            "isCorrect": "--",
                            "name": "--",
                            "subQuestions": []
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "-------": "-------"
          }
        ],
        "dataMap": null
      }
```

Iam using Spring MVC + Hibernate criteria API + Jackson library
So, can anyone please tell me the best way to exclude objects (complete object based on some condition) from list while serialization ??

Comment: The thing is, while serializing objects, either you do your whole JSON array or none of ti. So the best way to do it, unfortunately, is to serialize all the list, and then remove the unwanted items.

Comment: @DamCx, Do you mean need to iterate all records one by one??

Comment: You will be able to serialise all your objects in one operation, by using `ObjectMapper` from Jackson

Comment: Yes iam able to serialize, let say i have 100 records apprx, 30 records are parent records out of 100. So i need to exclude remaining 70 child records (have parent id) from the list

Comment: I know what you mean, but as you can't really have a way to filter while doing the serialization, you will have to do it once your objects are serialized.

Comment: Do we have any interceptor mechanism in jackson data serialization (spring rest)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135080/discussion-between-damcx-and-developer).

Comment: After serialization data will be in JSON format
We need to do filter/excluse in HTML workplace right??

Answer (score 0):

As we talked with @Developer, the best way to answer this problem will be to serialize all the objects, using some tool, just as `ObjectMapper` from `Jackson`, and once the List is built, iterate over it to have only the elements you want to keep.

Perfomance-wise, that's not the best thing, but this will make sure you won't miss any wanted items